# How to tackle a multilabel classification problem

Tags: nlp, lstm, rnn, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I am trying to build a LSTM model for a multiclass classification problem on textual data. Until now, I have only built a model when one input belongs to one of the categories. What do I do when one input can belong to more than one class (i.e.: one entry of data can belong to 2-3 categories)? Can anyone help me with some blogs or resources to build an intuition for making such a model?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the proportion of such entries in your dataset? If it is less, then removing such entries is the best choice.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have around 9000 data points, the number of training points per class varies from 450 to 1500 out of 9000 data points.

Comment: https://course.fast.ai/videos/?lesson=3                                                                                 thank me later go watch it get a great score sleep soundly have a good day and give some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

LSTMs, like any other neural net, implicitly support multi-label classification.  You should ensure that your output layer has $n$ neurons, one for each class, and you should use *logistic* activation rather than *softmax* activation (which is typically used for the final layer in multi-class problems).

Each neuron $N_i$ in the final layer will output a value between 0 and 1.  If the output of $N_i$ is greater than 0.5, then the example is a member of label $i$.

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-classification-and-class-activation-map-on-fashion-mnist-1454f09f5925)'s a pretty good article that might help.

Answer (score 0):

When each object can be classified from 0 to multiple categories, it is a **multilabel** classification problem. There are several approachs to tackle this, the most known is probably the **One-vs-the-Rest** strategy : it consists in dividing the problem into a multitude of binary classification tasks, for each possible label.

However, deep neural networks support inherently multilabel classification. Each neuron of the final classification layer can be associated with a label. As you would like to have multiple output neurons with high values if an object has several tags, you should use a **sigmoid activation function** on the final layer and the **binary crossentropy loss function**.

There are [several tutorials](https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff) on the web.